# How to use previous expression's result in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala

```scala
// when in Scala REPL
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1
```

How can I reuse an expression's result in another expression?

For example:

```scala
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1

scala> the_previous_expression + 1
// = 2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "command"? `1` is not a command, it is an expression, more precisely, an integer literal expression. Commands start with a colon `:`, and are, for example `:help`, `:reset`, `:quit`, etc. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "output"? The output in your case is the string `"res0: Int = 1"`. Is that what you want? Or are you talking about the expression's result value, which would be the integer `1`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the previous expression's result by looking its REPL output on the next line, the word starting with **res**.

```scala
// when in Scala REPL
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1         // <-- res0 is the handle that you can use
```

**For example:**

```scala
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1

scala> res0 + 1
res1: Int = 2

scala> res1 + 1
res2: Int = 3

// and so on
```

**You can also use it with others:**

```scala
scala> () => "hey!" // anonymous function
res0: () => String = $$Lambda$1104/1658578510@6cff61fc

scala> res0()
res1: String = hey
```

Comment: This answer finds the variable for a specified resN result, however what is wanted is the *previous* result.